# Remove animation/delay on Command+Tab

Tags: macos, desktop, spaces, animation

When switching to a full-screen app on a different space there is a noticeable delay (and jerkiness) with the animation during which further presses of <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> have no effect. This continues for a fraction of a second even *after* the animation has finished.

It's very annoying and disruptive if keypresses are simply ignored by the OS, and it's beyond me how such an obvious massive flaw goes past quality control at Apple (and how most macOS users seemingly just live with it).

Is there a way to **completely remove** the fade (or slide) animation when you switch (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to a full-screen app that is on a different space?

Comment: Go to System Preferences > Accessibility > Display. And turn on "Reduce motion".

Answer (score 2):

> Go to System Preferences > Accessibility > Display. And turn on
> "Reduce motion".

Credit to John Gilmer in the [comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288259/remove-animation-delay-on-commandtab#comment592715_288259) above.