# Disable command-tab sliding/fading animation

Tags: macos

Is there a way to completely disable the animation when using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>? I want an instant tab switch, similar to windows. I know of the reduce motion setting. However this just converts the animation from slide to fade. Is there a way to remove it completely? I read a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288259/remove-animation-delay-on-commandtab#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=0-,Go%20to%20System%20Preferences%20%3E%20Accessibility%20%3E%20Display.,turn%20on%20%22Reduce%20motion%22.), the answers just point to the reduce motion. There probably is no native way to do it, so I am willing to use third-party apps.